# Render View Only After all Data has been fetched from Service?

Tags: web-services, angular, routes

I have a table Component where when the user Selects a particular row he is Redirected to a different route to a team component .
I want to Load the View Of the New Route when all the data from the Service has been Fetched by the Component .

How to Prevent the View From rendering till the Time the whole data has been fetched from Service in the New components OnInit Method.
in angular 1 there was ngCloak how to do it in Angular 2 .

I have used ngIf but for a split second till the data loads the div pops up and then disappears

My table Component

```
  onSubmit(team:any){
    this.teamId = team._links.team.href.split('/').pop(-1);
    this.competitionService.storeTeamCrest(team.crestURI);
    this.router.navigate(['team', {id: this.teamId}]);
  }
```

Service

```
 storeTeamCrest(link:string){
    this.teamCrest = link;
  }

  getPlayers(id:string){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('X-Auth-Token', 'XXX');
    return this.http.get('https://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/'+id+'/players',{headers:headers}).map(response => response.json())
  }

  getFixtures(id:string){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('X-Auth-Token', '7c94f28bddf34648bd9a6f5c2e2da0f0');
    return this.http.get('https://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/'+id+'/fixtures',{headers:headers}).map(response => response.json())
  }
```

Team Component

```
 ngOnInit(){
    this.teamId = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.teamCrest = this.competitionService.teamCrest;
    this.getPlayers();
  }

  getPlayers(){
    this.competitionService.getPlayers(this.teamId).subscribe(player => this.players = player.players);
  }
```

Team Component Template

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div *ngFor="let player of players"#data>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="well box">
            <img class="avatar" src="{{teamCrest}}">
            <h4> {{player.name}} </h4>
            <hr style="background-color:black;" />
            <span class="label label-default"><strong>Position :</strong> {{player.position}} </span><br/>
            <span class="label label-primary"><strong>Jersey Number :</strong> {{player.jerseyNumber}} </span><br/>
            <span class="label label-success"><strong>Date Of birth :</strong> {{player.dateOfBirth}}</span><br/>
            <span class="label label-info"><strong>Nationality :</strong> {{player.nationality}} </span><br/>
            <span class="label label-warning"><strong>Contract Untill :</strong> {{player.contractUntil}}</span><br/>
            <span class="label label-success"><strong>Market Value :</strong> {{player.marketValue}}</span><br/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div *ngIf="!players?.length">
    <h3>No Player Data found For the Selected Team</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried [resolve](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Resolve-interface.html) in Route?

Comment: I haven't how to do that actually

Comment: But with resolve we only get data if it is returned but i know some times the object will be null . I want to show that error message but the error message will vanish if it has values. Check this line 
<div *ngIf="!players?.length">
    <h3>No Player Data found For the Selected Team</h3>
</div>

Comment: I don't think so. Resolve gets the list which can be empty, then your view gets rendered. BTW I've never had problems with ngIf. If placed at the div.container you should not see any flickering IMO.

Comment: How can we implement Resolve in this case ?

Answer (score 5):

handle the (complete) => {} callback inside subscribe ([Subscribe Docs](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/subscribe.md)) and set a boolean to true. Check against this boolean with your *ngIf.

So, inside your Team Component:

```
players:any[] = [];
loadCompleted:boolean = false;
ngOnInit(){
    this.teamId = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.teamCrest = this.competitionService.teamCrest;
    this.getPlayers();
  }

  getPlayers(){
    this.loadCompleted = false;
    this.competitionService.getPlayers(this.teamId)
       .subscribe(
                  player => this.players = player.players,
                  (error) => console.error(error), 
                  () => this.loadCompleted = true)
       );
  }
```

then in your HTML template:

```
<div *ngIf="loadCompleted" class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div *ngFor="let player of players" #data>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="well box">
            <img class="avatar" src="{{teamCrest}}">
            <h4> {{player.name}} </h4>
            <hr style="background-color:black;" />
            <span class="label label-default"><strong>Position :</strong> {{player.position}} </span><br/>
            <span class="label label-primary"><strong>Jersey Number :</strong> {{player.jerseyNumber}} </span><br/>
            <span class="label label-success"><strong>Date Of birth :</strong> {{player.dateOfBirth}}</span><br/>
            <span class="label label-info"><strong>Nationality :</strong> {{player.nationality}} </span><br/>
            <span class="label label-warning"><strong>Contract Untill :</strong> {{player.contractUntil}}</span><br/>
            <span class="label label-success"><strong>Market Value :</strong> {{player.marketValue}}</span><br/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div *ngIf="loadCompleted && !players?.length">
    <h3>No Player Data found For the Selected Team</h3>
</div>
```

If i understood your question, this should do what you want.
Just a side note: in your backend service, IMHO, you shouldn't return null if there aren't players for the input teamId, but an empty List/Array/whatever.

Comment: Superbbbbbbbbb!